# How does Java Determine methods call at runtime in polymorphism?

Tags: java, jvm, polymorphism, bytecode

While the main principle of polymorphism is decoupling "what from who" in term of `types`, but what confuses me how does method-call mechanism finds out and calls the correct method body in polymorphism.

Since in java all method binding is `late-binding` unless the method is `static`, `final` or `private`, and late-binding is done by JVM which precomputes `method table` for each class and then do a table look up during runtime in normal method call.

But the same thing happens during polymorphism too. For example

Suppose I've a Generic class `Cycle` with a `ride()` method

```
class Cycle {

    public void ride(){
        System.out.println("I'm Riding generic Cycle()");
    }

}
```

And i have three Specialized Class `Bicycle` `Tricycle` and `Unicycle` which extends Generic class `Cycle` and overrides its `ride()` method.

```
class Bicycle extends Cycle {

    public void ride() {
        System.out.println("I'm riding Bicycle");

    }

}

class Tricycle extends Cycle{

    public void ride() {
        System.out.println("I'm riding Tricycle ");

    }

}

class Unicycle extends Cycle {

    public void ride() {
        System.out.println("I'm Riding Unicycle ");

    }

}
```

This is the `TestRide` class to Test the above Polymorphism.

```
public class TestRide {

    public static void ride(Cycle c){
        c.ride();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Cycle Cycling = new Cycle();
        ride(Cycling);

        Bicycle bi = new Bicycle();
        ride(bi);

        Tricycle tri = new Tricycle();
        ride(tri);

        Unicycle uni = new Unicycle();
        ride(uni);
    }

}
```

The Output is

```
I'm Riding generic Cycle()
I'm riding Bicycle
I'm riding Tricycle 
I'm Riding Unicycle
```

Byte Code:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=5, args_size=1
         0: new           #17                 // class com/polymorphism/Cycle
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #24                 // Method com/polymorphism/Cycle."
<init>":()V
         7: astore_1
         8: aload_1
         9: invokestatic  #25                 // Method ride:(Lcom/polymorphism/
Cycle;)V
        12: new           #27                 // class com/polymorphism/Bicycle
        15: dup
        16: invokespecial #29                 // Method com/polymorphism/Bicycle
."<init>":()V
        19: astore_2
        20: aload_2
        21: invokestatic  #25                 // Method ride:(Lcom/polymorphism/
Cycle;)V
        24: new           #30                 // class com/polymorphism/Tricycle

        27: dup
        28: invokespecial #32                 // Method com/polymorphism/Tricycl
e."<init>":()V
        31: astore_3
        32: aload_3
        33: invokestatic  #25                 // Method ride:(Lcom/polymorphism/
Cycle;)V
        36: new           #33                 // class com/polymorphism/Unicycle

        39: dup
        40: invokespecial #35                 // Method com/polymorphism/Unicycl
e."<init>":()V
        43: astore        4
        45: aload         4
        47: invokestatic  #25                 // Method ride:(Lcom/polymorphism/
Cycle;)V
        50: return
```

Even in the bytecode its just as usual method call with `invokestatic` and `invokespecial` while i thought it would use `invokedynamic` to figure out the version of the method that is appropriate for the actual type of the object. But that was not the case.

So how does Java figure out the actual method call during polymorphism while we just pass an upcasted Object in the `ride()` method  like `ride(bi)` in `TestRide` class ?

EDIT: RIDE method ByteCode

```
public static void ride(com.polymorphism.Cycle);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokevirtual #16                 // Method com/polymorphism/Cycle.r
ide:()V
         4: return
```

Comment: Maybe your test case is too simple. If the Java compiler knows at compile-time, what method will be called, there is no need for bytecode that does anything dynamically.

Comment: `invokedynamic` was introduced in JVM bytecode for dynamic method lookup that *doesn't* follow Java's method lookup. Why would a Java compiler use it? Virtual method dispatch is done with `invokevirtual` and `invokeinterface`. Note that a Java compiler is of course free to use `invokedynamic` if it wants to. The Java Language Specification says nothing about how Java has to be compiled, it doesn't even say it has to be compiled at all, it could just as well be interpreted.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Got your point :) . But the question of how it does it still remains

Comment: You're posting the byte-code of main(), where there is 0 polymorphic method call being made: only constructor calls and static method calls (to `ride()`). The polymorphic method call is made in `TestRide.ride()`

Comment: @JBNizet :  Posted that code

Comment: @JBNizet True, but it looks like the code of `TestRide.ride` was inlined by the Java compiler.

Comment: @mastov no. It has 4 invokestatic calls to the static method ride() taking a Cycle as argument.

Comment: @mastov No, it was just the calls to the constructors followed by calls to the static method.

Comment: @JBNizet I stand corrected.

Comment: So, what's your question exactly? You can see that the byte-code has an invokevirtual instruction, and that instruction will look for the right method thanks the concrete type of the cycle and to the method lookup table. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual

Comment: @JBNizet My question is how does the BASE class `Cycle` figure out the Correct method of the Other derived Class `method` which it calls based upon the type of Object of derived class ?

Comment: The base class doesn't figure out anything. invokevirtual has the Cycle object on which the ride() method is called as the first argument on the stack. It gets the *concrete* class of that Cycle object (and thus gets BiCycle, or TriCycle, for example). Then it looks for the ride() method in that concrete class, following the procedure described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much for that link .. now i understand it clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

First off `invokedynamic` is for Java 8 lambdas and non-Java code, so you can forget about that.

Apart from that, there are four invoke instructions (`invokespecial`, `invokestatic`, `invokevirtual`, and `invokeinterface`). You can see the precise semantics in the JVM sepcification, but the bottom line is that `invokevirtual` and `invokeinterface` are *virtual* method calls, i.e. the actual method called is chosen at runtime based on the conrete type of the target.

The only virtual call in your code is in TestRide.ride. The listed target is `Cycle.ride:()V`. However, since it is a virtual call, the JVM will check the actual type of the first argument at runtime and call the most derived version of that method.

This is similar to virtual method calls in C++, except that the abstraction of the JVM and JIT compilation allows the potential for more optimized implementations.

Also note that this is not to be confused with method overloading, which is a form of compile-time polymorphism. For overloaded methods, the compiler chooses which one to call based on the compile time type of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think @JBNizet figured out the solution already in the comments (and my guess turned out to be wrong). But since he doesn't post it as an answer, I'll do it:

The `main` method isn't supposed to show any dynamic behavior because it is always ever going to call that *one* *single* method `TestRide.ride(Cycle c)`. There is no other possible method, so nothing to figure out.

The dynamic method call is inside that method `TestRide.ride(Cycle c)`. And now that you posted that code, indeed we see a dynamic method dispatch using `invokevirtual`. So, after all, no surprises. The dynamic method dispatch is there.