# Why it is called runtime polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am extending a class but I am not able to figure out why the **JVM decides only at runtime** which method to call. I mean when I do `A obj=new B();`, isn't it obvious that the method in `B` will be called ? 
Maybe it is not obvious for compiler but I want to know the details.

Code is as follows :

```
class A
{
    String getName(String name) {
        return "super";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    @Override
    String getName(String name) {
        return "sub";
    }
}

public class Overload 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A obj=new B();
        System.out.println(obj.getName(null));
    }     
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Java Determine methods call at runtime in polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678928/how-does-java-determine-methods-call-at-runtime-in-polymorphism)

Comment: That's a very special case. What if you write `A obj = getSomeA()`?

Comment: `A obj=new B()` -> Here you have explicitly used an instance of `B`. What if you were calling a third party api and you didn't know what type of Object it would return?. For example -`List l = getAListOfSomething()`

Comment: @TheLostMind so it is basically the type of object which is decided at runtime ?

Comment: @Amol Yes. Which you cannot predict and only runtime can decide :)

Comment: @Amol - Yes. There is no way for the compiler to know which instance (implementation) will be used during runtime.

Comment: Also, the JIT compiler of JVM will be able to optimize that at runtime, if it can "prove" it can only be this one class.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler can only able to check their types and it's functionality is limited. Hence it cannot actually run and see the program output. That is why it belong to run time.

Compiler check it's type, and runtime bind it's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You know it holds a reference of B, because the complexity of code here is simple. 
What if you had class 'C' also extending from class 'A' and if the responsibility of initializing obj is with some other class or may be some config.

Unlike as in compile-type polymorphism where we as well as the compiler can see the single statement and decide which method can be called.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see this scenario:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract void sayHello();
}

public class B extends A{
    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("B says Hello!");
    }
}

public class C extends A{
    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("C says Hello!");
    }
}

public class FactoryA{
    public static A getInstance(String type){
        if("B".equals(type)){
            return new B();
        }
        else if("C".equals(type)){
            return new C();
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say that now you ask the factory to get instance based on the String parameter, like this:

```
A a = FactoryA.getInstance("B"); // the string can come user-input
a.sayHello();
```

In this output will be "B says Hello!", because the instance you get from Factory's method is an instance of B, which depends on the String parameter passed to it.

In this case it may not be known at the run time which method will be called (B's sayHello() or C's sayHello()). That's why it is called runtime polymorphism.

*Because the decision was taken at runtime.*